# Undefined variable: mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy creando un proyecto mini solo para pruebas pero tengo un error al intentar entrar a la pagina, y pues soy un poco nuevo en esto y no se como solucionarlo :/

he intentado investigar por otros lugares pero no puedo buscar una respuesta que me ayude, no se si me podrian ayudar ustedes.

Error:

> Undefined variable: mysqli

Codigo:

```html
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'users');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$id = 1; // Aquí defines la variable que contiene el id del usuario
$sql = "SELECT username,trabajo FROM users WHERE id = ".$id;
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    if ($resultado->num_rows === 0){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    }
}


if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: No se pudo conectar. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Html:

```html
<?php

require_once "config.php";
session_start();
 
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

?>
 
<p><? $_SESSION['username']['username'] ?></b> tu trabajo es: <? $_SESSION['username']['trabajo'] ?></p>
```

Comment: Buenas, aun sigue el problema Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli - if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {

Answer (score 1):

Tu error radica en este segmento de código pues efectivamente la variable `$mysqli` no existe

```
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql))
```

Al momento de que tratas de ejecutar la consulta, lo que necesitas es invocar al método `query()` encadenándolo con la variable que almacena tu conexión la cual es `$link`

Entonces debería quedar así:

```
if ($resultado = $link->query($sql))
```

Al margen de esto tu consulta debería por mejora implementar las sentencias preparadas, [justo aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) puedes leer mas al respecto

**Referencia**

- [driver mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)